# Can't get cloned element to keep originals events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to clone an element that is passed into a function and all events associated to it, as there are `$('.example').on('click', function(e) ... )}` events like this defined in document ready.

So I do following:

```
$('.example').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        surpriseMe($(this));
});
```

and I try to clone this element along side its events here (I need to grab parent as `.html()` returns only inner html, hence element itself) :

```
function surpriseMe(element) {

    var newElement = element.parent().clone(true,true).html();

    surprise.insertBefore(element.parent());

    if (numElements == 3) {
        newMonth = $('<li class="item-dragable-placeholder">'+ newElement +'</li>
    }  

}
```

I believe `true, true` inside `.clone()` should force parent also grab its children events, but whenever I click on newly placed element, nothing happens

Comment: Use event delegation and do not worry about it....

Comment: @epascarello ahh..., do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: While I agree with epascarello, you should understand the problem. jQuery events are only bound and occur within jQuery. So when you `.clone(true, true)`, you are correct - events would be included in the clone as well. But as soon as you use `.html()`, you're literally only getting the element's HTML - no events, data, anything else. Depending on what you actually intended to do (there are some typos I think), I think you could have done: `element.parent().prepend(element.clone(true, true));`

Comment: @Ian I see, thanks for explanation, I read more about it after posting the question and was confused as I missed out on the .html() bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use event delegation...

Change:

```
$('.example').on('click', function(e) { ...
```

To:

```
$(document).on('click', '.example', function(e) { ...
```

**Note:** Instead of using `document`, find the closest ancestor element (container) that's available on page load and use that.

Answer (score 0):

when you do your insert, instead of inserting the new element, you ask to insert only the html, remove the html part, it will give you the element and its functionalities.

```
var newElement = element.parent().clone(true,true).html();
```

See the following (example)[http://jsfiddle.net/dshun/1j9khfnc/4/](please note, since the example code given is not complete. For example, the variable surprise, numElements are not declared. I made some assumptions in my fiddle)

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var numElements=0;

    function surpriseMe(element) {

       var newElement = element.parent().clone(true,true);
       newElement.insertBefore( ".inner" );
       numElements++;

       if (numElements == 3) {
         newMonth = $('li.item-dragable-placeholder').insert(newElement);
       }  

    }

    $('.example').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      surpriseMe($(this));
    });
});
```